# How to access getResources() in non-activity class in Android?

Tags: android

Please, refer the code below

```
ForegroundColorSpan ss = new ForegroundColorSpan(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red_text));
```

This is what i'm going to do, but it through an error.

Comment: You can get context only from Application,Service or Activity classes

Comment: I'm able to access context, by passing it as a parameter from activity class. Facing issue regarding getResources.

Answer (score 3):

In the non-activity Java class you can do,

```
public static void doSomething(Context ctx){
        ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.app_icon);
    }
```

And call it from your `activity` class.

```
javaClassObj.doSomething(this);
```

Comment: I'm doing the same thing as you mentioned, but it throws force close error, only difference is instead getDrawable() I'm calling getColor()

Answer (score 0):

What's the error you are getting?

Where's your context came from?

You can try do a "Clean" in your project, or try to get another context.

Or passa the context by parameters when you call the non-activity class....

[]s
Bertan

Comment: Force close error i'm getting and I'm passing context as a parameter from activity class.

Comment: Please, paste here your Stacktrace for further help :)... You did the "CLEAN" / REFRESH your project? It's weird but with me resolved some hours of problem...

Comment: 09-13 18:04:20.001: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(900): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NullPointerException
and also did clean-up

Comment: Where is your context came from?

How you get the context?

I think your context is null, and when you get the Resources(),trow the NullPointerException,

Comment: I'm passing context as a parameter from activity class to non-activity class

Comment: Okay, but how you get the context... It's getContext(), or getApplicationContext(), getBaseContext(), and what the component you are getting the Context, it's in the Activity, Dialog, AlertDialog, View, EditText... Post the code when you calling the class and the constructor of your class...

Comment: It's getContext(), and the component is getResources()

Answer (score 0):

Pass activity context or application context to the constructor of non-activity class and use this context.

Comment: I'm passing context as a parameter from activity class